# How to use date_make_date() in drupal 7?

Tags: datetime

I am porting custom module from drupal 6 to drupal 7 
I have the following code:

```
 $local_date = new DateTime($dateTxt);
 $iso_date_string = date_format_date($local_date, 'custom', 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
 $utc_date = date_make_date($iso_date_string, $user_timezone_name, DATE_DATETIME);
```

What can be the alternative for [date_make_time()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!date!date_api.module/function/date_make_date/6) in drupal 7?

https://www.drupal.org/node/1075476

> this error is due to a change in the Date API module, instead of
>   date_make_date you need to use the new DateObject class. see "D7
>   Changes" here: http://drupal.org/project/date
>
> I fixed this as follows, but not sure if I'm using the DateObject
>   properly.
>
> Edit this block of code in agenda.module, line 354

```
  // If the Date API is installed, we can do better at DST times   if (module_exists('date_api')) {
    $start               = date_make_date($event['start timestamp'], NULL, DATE_UNIX);
    $event['start time'] = date_format_date($start, 'custom', $block->timeformat);
    $end                 = date_make_date($event['end timestamp'], NULL, DATE_UNIX);
    $event['end time']   = date_format_date($end, 'custom', $block->timeformat);   }
```

replace with

```
  // If the Date API is installed, we can do better at DST times   if (module_exists('date_api')) {
    $start               = new DateObject($event['start timestamp'], NULL);
    $event['start time'] = $start->format($block->timeformat);
    $end                 = new DateObject($event['end timestamp'], NULL);
    $event['end time']   = $end->format($block->timeformat);   } alternatively, just comment out the whole block.
```

I looked in the above node but not sure about the new DateObject() ?

new DateObject()

---

Comment: It's declared in the date_api.module file...

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to the date_make_date function in D7 is the [DateObject](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!date!date_api!date_api.module/class/DateObject/7), which extends the PHP [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

To make your code work properly, you'd do something like this (untested):

```
$local_date = new DateTime($dateTxt, $timezone); //$timezone can be string or object
$iso_date_string = $local_date->toIso(); //returns the ISO string for the date
$utc_date = clone $local_date; //don't want pass by reference
$utc_date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC')); //set the new timezone to return
$utc_date_iso = $utc_date->toIso(); //returns $local_date converted to UTC as an ISO string.
```

I'm not totally sure what you want to do, but this, hopefully, will get you on the right path.